# Show a div when hover and hide when blur

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show divs when radio button labels are hovered.

In html,

```
  <input id="hello" type="radio" name="greetings" value="hello">
  <label for="hello" id="hello-label">test</label>
  <input id="hi" type="radio" name="greetings" value="hi">
  <label for="i" id="hi-label">test</label>

  <div class="fields-div>
      <input id="f1" type="radio" name="fields" value="f1">
      <label for="f1" >test</label>
      <input id="f2" type="radio" name="fields" value="f2">
      <label for="f2" >test</label>
  </div>
...
```

In css,

```
.fields-div {
    position: absolute; top: 0; 
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

In js,

```
$('#hello-label').hover(function() {
    $('.fields-div').css({'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'});
}
$('#hello-label').blur(function() {
    $('.fields-div').css({'opacity': '0', 'visibility': 'hidden'});
}
```

When a user hovers one of the radio buttons, it displays an associated div and the div remains on but when the radio button is out of focus, the div should be hid. But the div is still showing. What's missing here?

Comment: Did you read the [doco for `.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)? Your function will be called when the mouse enters *and* again when it leaves. But you can instead pass it two functions, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave. The `.blur()` event relates to the element losing focus, which is not related to mouse movements.

Comment: This was the reason that it didn't work. It should happen when it loses its focus so the fields-div can remain to enable to select one of the fields. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use of pure css, Like this:

```
#hello-label:hover ~ .fields-div {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
.fields-div {
    position: relative;
    top: 0; 
    display: none;
}

#hello-label:hover ~ .fields-div {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
  <input id="hello" type="radio" name="greetings" value="hello">
  <label for="hello" id="hello-label">test</label>
  <input id="hi" type="radio" name="greetings" value="hi">
  <label for="i" id="hi-label">test</label>

  <div class="fields-div">
      <input id="f1" type="radio" name="fields" value="f1">
      <label for="f1" >test</label>
      <input id="f2" type="radio" name="fields" value="f2">
      <label for="f2" >test</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Because I have to click the items in 'fields-div' but when I do it it disappears. That's why I have to go with JQuery. Anyway thanks.

Comment: You Are Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`

[.mouseenter()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

> Description: Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

[.mouseleave()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

> Description: Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

```js
$('#hello-label').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.fields-div').css({
    'opacity': '1',
    'visibility': 'visible'
  });

}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.fields-div').css({
    'opacity': '0',
    'visibility': 'hidden'
  });

});
```

```css
.fields-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hello" type="radio" name="greetings" value="hello">
<label for="hello" id="hello-label">test</label>
<input id="hi" type="radio" name="greetings" value="hi">
<label for="i" id="hi-label">test</label>

<div class="fields-div">
  <input id="f1" type="radio" name="fields" value="f1" />
  <label for="f1">test</label>
  <input id="f2" type="radio" name="fields" value="f2" />
  <label for="f2">test</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missing some close brackets
and you can just use `toggleClass` to toggle your state.

```js
$('#hello-label').hover(function() {
  $('.fields-div').toggleClass('toggle_show');
})
```

```css
.fields-div {
  position: absolute; top: 0; 
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.toggle_show{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hello" type="radio" name="greetings" value="hello">
  <label for="hello" id="hello-label">test</label>
  <input id="hi" type="radio" name="greetings" value="hi">
  <label for="i" id="hi-label">test</label>

  <div class="fields-div">
      <input id="f1" type="radio" name="fields" value="f1">
      <label for="f1" >test</label>
      <input id="f2" type="radio" name="fields" value="f2">
      <label for="f2" >test</label>
  </div>
```